# webpack child_process.exec - TypeError: error is not a function

Tags: node.js, webpack, child-process

Trying to execute child_process.exe using webpack but getting error that exec is not a function. The script is working in node prompt.

**test.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

describe('node version', function nodeVersion() {
    it('Should display Node Version', (done) => {
      exec('node -v', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
      console.log('stderr: ', stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ', error);
      }
    done();
    });
  });
});
```

Is there anyway we can execute shell commands like child_process.exec on browser?

Comment: Is there anyway we can execute shell commands like child_process.exec on browser

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to run `child_process` in the browser because JavaScript in the browser is not allowed to create processes. Thankfully there is no way to run a shell script in the browser, otherwise any website would have access to your machine and the bad things you could do with it are endless (e.g. delete everything with `rm -rf /` or at least what you've permission for).

Comment: But by using webpack-dev-server can I get the test results on browser for the above test. Getting an error that exec is not a function as of now. Thanks

Comment: What if you are in chromium embedded framework with node enabled for example, as you can write pseudo-native apps the "website-way". There you have access to child_process, fs, path, ...

Hell is mocking these modules for the tests, which have no node (so you need to mock them some way, you do not need the real modules for tests - you do not want to test node modules with your app.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute this in cypress you can do

```
cy.exec('node -v').then((result) => {
 console.log(result);
});
```